# Crystal Report Error-Could not load file or assembly

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2008

I design ERP for my company and it is working fine. On reports side I am using crystal reports 2008. On my developing Laptop reports are working fine but on user side I am getting error

[image: image of error]

I tried

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

but no luck.

I installed crystal reports 2008 on user pc still not working, I tried sap crystal reports runtime still no luck.

My code to view crystal reports is:

```
Private Sub cpvreport()

        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("\\192.168.1.150\Bashir Impex Files\Department Folders\IT\cpv.rpt")

        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = CashPaymentidTextBox.Text
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = _
   cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = _
   crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("cpvid")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        Form5.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

        Form5.Show()

    End Sub
```

ALSO

Whenever I am viewing my report it always asks for SQL Server password, how I can finish it?

Comment: Its pretty clear from the error that it can't load one of the Crystal Report assemblies. You need to make sure the correct runtimes are installed. This will have nothing to do with sql server. Go through the crystal documentation or your installation file.

Comment: i tried many runtimes but i am still facing the issue. can u please recommend me any runtimes or any method to solve it

Comment: Sorry, not a Crystal Reports guy. Most installers know what to include, if not then google it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a runtime as TomC wrote in a comment.
The CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll should appear somewhere in your user's machine. A proper runtine should resolve this.

Check what version of Visual Studio you use. Until VS 2010 a runtime was installed with VS installation (https://support.microsoft.com/pl-pl/help/317789/support-for-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio) - so you could easly find a runtime matching your VS, in newer versions you need to check the proper runtime (matching your Crystal version) and install it.

In case of user and password asked while viewing a report. You need to use ODBC Source (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC).
On your local machine create an ODBC and save credentials to your test DB.
On your user's machine create similar ODBC Source (same name of ODBC as on your local machine), but set connection to real DB. I am not sure, but I think that in both sources a DB name needs to be identical.
Inside a Crystal report you need to point this ODBC source. Then on a client machine a report will connect to a source with same name.

Then a report should run.

Comment: thank you for your reply urula but your link to microsoft is not showing the version i can use of crystal reports but my .net is 2010

Comment: i follow ur steps regarding ODBC and configured it but still facing issues . i did it in my laptop where i am developing ERP ... i hope i did right

Comment: I didn't notice you are using a control, so my unswer is inaccurate.
Have your seen this? It looks like you are missing ApplyLogOnInfo : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965631/crystal-reports-passing-credentials-to-the-report-so-that-it-only-shows-data-for

Answer (score 0):

problem soved ...... i install latest runtime from below website and change COMPILE option to ANY USER instead of x86 and it worked

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/

but password issue still not resolved